# How to get an 'ion-card' to be smaller, but still centered in the middle of the screen (ionic 4)

Tags: ionic-framework

Please, I would appreciate some help. I'm sure is pretty simple but I can't get over the ionic 4 classes that they put behind the elements, and I need an ion-card to be small.

This is my first time on StackOverFlow.  Here is my code:

```
<ion-content color="tertiary" padding margin>
<ion-card color="medium" >
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-title>Elija su Zona</ion-title>  
      <ion-list> 
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of zonas">
          <ion-label (click)=gotoHomeByZona(id)>{{item.nombre}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, have you taken a look at the Ionic 4 documentation on classes? If so, please share what you have tried thus far including looking up documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:80%; margin: 0 auto">
  <ion-card color="medium" >
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-title>Elija su Zona</ion-title>  
      <ion-list> 
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of zonas">
          <ion-label (click)=gotoHomeByZona(id)>{{item.nombre}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</div>
```